# Как очистить recyclerView в Android

Tags: kotlin, recyclerview.adapter, firebase-database

Делаю чат-мессенджер на котлине, работает по принципу: Загрузка данных о зарегистрированных пользователях хранится в RealTime DataBase (FireBase), при отправке письма от пользователя A пользователю B, сохраняется JSON в таком виде на сервере. После чего через прослушиватель  загружаются письма в диалог.

Добавил кнопку очищения диалога, adapter.clear(), диалог очищается, но прослушиватель загружает обратно. Нужно, чтобы диалог очищался с сохранением данных в FireBase.

[image: Данные в RealTime DataBase]

Comment: можно попробовать закидывать новый пустой даилог и сохранять его там

Comment: Не удаляй данные локально, а удали на сервере, но тогда и у второго пользователя удалятся все данные. Как вариант если юзер очистил сообщения, то больше не поставляй ему сообщения посланные ранее даты очистки.

Comment: > Как вариант если юзер очистил сообщения, то больше не поставляй ему сообщения посланные ранее даты очистки. 

В принципе ты сейчас сформулировал мой вопрос.